# Format of jsonp response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I need a jsonp response from cross domain url. My jsonp code is here

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        jsonpCallback: "domaincheck",
        data:{
            id:k,
            domain:l
        },
        url: 'http://example.com/param',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
```

In the php file, the output is like this:

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['callback']."([Correct])";
?>
```

I knew that the data what I am returning back is incorrect. Because I think we should pass response as json data only. But in this case, sending only "correct" as response, how should we set it, so that we get the response correctly.

The error what I get in console is this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: `[Correct]` isn't valid json, therefore `callback([Correct])` wouldn't be valid jsonp.

Comment: `async: false` and `contentType` are useless for jsonp, they get ignored.

Comment: @KevinB I knew [correct] is invalid json. What else can we send as response in this case

Comment: Make it valid? `["Correct"]`